# Insert datetime into cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-storm

I am trying to insert data from storm to cassandra. It is of string type initially.

My java class has following code:

```
String insertQuery1
            = "insert into fault.as_fo_ag_uc ("
            + "host,"
            + "trigger,"
            + "eventtime,uuiddefault) "
            + "values(?,?,?,?)";    

BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
boundStatement.setString(1, dto.getHost());
boundStatement.setString(2, dto.getTrigger());
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(dto.getEventTime());
boundStatement.setDate(3, ts);
boundStatement.setString(4, dto.getUIDDefault());
```

Here eI get error that eventtime is of type timestamp. As I have converted to timestamp but it is notworking. I also have tried using Simple Date Formater to format it into date type

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,z");
boundStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(df.parse(dto.getEventTime)).getTime()));
```

The error is "EventTime is of type timestamp". My cassandra driver version is 2.1.7.

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value
>   eventime is of type timestamp     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.checkType(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:89)
>   ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:?]    at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractData.setString(AbstractData.java:157)
>   ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:?]    at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.setString(BoundStatement.java:499)
>   ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:?]    at
>   storm.starter.bolt.CassandraWriterBolt.execute(CassandraWriterBolt.java:219)
>   [classes/:?]  at
>   backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.execute(BasicBoltExecutor.java:50)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$tuple_action_fn__5696.invoke(executor.clj:690)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5615.invoke(executor.clj:436)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at
>   backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at
>   backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:127)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at
>   backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:106)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at
>   backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707$fn__5758.invoke(executor.clj:819)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at
>   backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:479)
>   [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
>   [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [?:1.7.0_79]

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: It's also unclear why you are creating `Timestamp` and `java.sql.Date` objects when `setDate` simply expects a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis java 2.1.7 has not setTimestamp function

Comment: What? Why are you talking about a `setTimestamp` method?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have declared my column as eventtime timestamp,

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Did I miss anything?

Comment: Yeah, and the [corresponding Java type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/javaClass2Cql3Datatypes_r.html) is `java.util.Date`, so I don't understand why in one case you try to use `java.sql.Timestamp` and in another `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just tried to mention what I have tried. The setDate function takes both but none worked. I have also tried boundStatement.setDate(3, df.parse(dto.getEventTime()));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setXyz` methods in [`BoundStatement`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.html) that expect an `int` argument interpret that value as an index starting at 0.

So your

```
boundStatement.setString(2, dto.getTrigger());
```

is actually trying to set the placeholder for the `eventtime` column in the CQL query.

Change your statement to start at 0 and go up to 3.

```
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
boundStatement.setString(0, dto.getHost());
boundStatement.setString(1, dto.getTrigger());
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(dto.getEventTime());
boundStatement.setDate(2, ts);
boundStatement.setString(3, dto.getUIDDefault());
```

Comment: That was duh moment!

Comment: What version of Cassandra / DataStax Java driver is this relevant for? From [the 4.6 docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.6/manual/core/#cql-to-java-type-mapping) at least, it appears that timestamps should be mapped to `java.time.Instant` instead of `java.sql.Timestamp` unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @RyanQuey From the link, it was 2.1. Seems they’ve changed it considerably since then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to or have to use `QueryBuilder` in the Java driver, you can call it using something like this:

```
session.execute(insertInto("table_name")
  .value("userId", literal("123"))
  .value("created_at", function("toTimestamp", function("now")))
).toCql());
```

(Assuming Cassandra 2.2 or later, for support to use `toTimestamp`; see docs on [2.2](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/old/CQL-2.2.html#timeFun))